# Model Validation not showing error messages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations, modelstate

I am developing an ASP.NET Core MVC web app, however, I am having a problem with the data annotations.

For `int` and `decimal`, I cannot override the default error message for the data annotations. For `string`, the data annotation works.

[This should be showing the required error message that I set, it is an `int`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49App.png)

[This is showing the correct error message - it is a `string`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMJcl.png)

[The is should be showing an error message that I set in it's model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRrMO.png)

This is happening for `int` and `decimal` data types as previously mentioned.
Here are the properties in my model:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide the model")]
    [StringLength(55, ErrorMessage = "The model is too long")]
    public string MODEL { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide the service period")]
    [Range(0, 5, ErrorMessage = "Please provide a smaller number")]
    [RegularExpression("([0-9]+)", ErrorMessage = "Not a number")]
    public int SERVICE_PERIOD { get; set; }
```

As I previously said, the `string` data type is working as expected, however, the `int` data type is not showing my own required error message, nor is it showing the error message that says it is not a number. The `decimal` data type error only working is the data annotation for when the number is longer than 5 numbers which is the Range data annotation.

I would appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: Didn't you ask the [exact same question a couple of hours ago on a different account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66322897/model-validation-issues-when-using-data-types-other-than-string), where someone told you not to use a RegularExpression validation on numbers?

Comment: @CodeCaster Sorry I'm not too sure what post you are speaking about? It says the page is not found as well?

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me.

Try this attribute:

```
[Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid integer Number")]
```

Or you can use regular expression:

```
[RegularExpression("([0-9]+)", ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid Number")]
public int bmi_number { get; set; }
```

Comment: The Range data annotation is working correctly, but the valid number data annotation is not working correctly, it says "The value 'XXX' is not valid for SERVICE_PERIOD."